# Were effects of a planetary magnetic field reversal observed on other planets than Earth?

Tags: earth, planet, core, magnetic-field

From geological records in rocks and minerals we know that the magnetic field of Earth changed its polarity multiple times in the history. See [Geomagnetic reversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geomagnetic_reversal).

Was a similar process of a planetary magnetic field reversal observed on other planets?

I suppose that the record could be in rocks directly found on the planet (i.e. Mars), on its moons or in asteroids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are such evidence in the case of Mars. Observations from [Mars Global Surveyor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Global_Surveyor) show evidences of crustal magnetization. In particular, this magnetization has extensive, east-west trending linear features in Terra Cimmeria and Terra Sirenum. These are probably reminiscent of magnetic features associated with a reversing dipole.

There are no such evidence in the case of Venus: Venus has no intrinsic magnetic field today (contrary to the common belief, its inability to maintain a dynamo activity is either due to its chemical and physical conditions unable to form a solid core, either du to an early complete core solidification; it is not due to its slow rotation), and could not have maintained a remanent crustal magnetization, because its crust would have been to hot during its dynamo activity (above the Curie point).

**Sources**:

- [Acuna et al. (1999)](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/284/5415/794.abstract)
- [Luhmann & Russell (1997)](http://www-ssc.igpp.ucla.edu/personnel/russel/papers/venus_mag/)